# Set and Get the Cookies in ASP.NET web forms

Tags: asp.net, cookies, httpcontext, string, is-empty

The cookies in Asp.net are killing me! This is my Code:

set the cookie:(Upload is an **asp:FileUpload** control for uploading image)

```
   HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("WorkingImage", Upload.FileName.ToString());
  cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

and this is the way I get it:

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["WorkingImage"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["WorkingImage"].Value.ToString() != "")
     { //....}
```

cookie value is "" when I run the project .
Is there any help?(please note that in other pages cookies can set and will got correctly)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example where we save a WorkingImage name in cookie

```
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("WorkingImage");
        cookie.Value = Upload.FileName.ToString(); // Upload is an asp:FileUpload control name for uploading image
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
        Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

Here is example for accessing our cookie and check for the cookie :

```
        if(Request.Cookies["WorkingImage"] != null)
        {
            var cookieValue=Request.Cookies["WorkingImage"].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using within handler inherit:

```
 System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```

Like this:

```
public class Handler : IHttpAsyncHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```

For more cookies tutorials in asp .net visit [this](http://www.codingfusion.com/Cookies).